# Angular 2 with SCSS and WebPack - Full reload when changing scss file

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

all ! I'm moving from gulp to Webpack and I've some basic doubts...

In gulp, when I change my scss file, it's recompile and show the changes on the browser very instantly.

Using webpack, if I change the scss file, this is not applying the changes without reload the browser. Can anybody help me with this ?

it's a very hello world application....

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.component.scss

```
main {
 padding: 1em;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
 color: red;
 display: block;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: 'raw'
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    })
]
};
```

Comment: Are you running webpack with HMR enabled?

Comment: Hey @FabioAntunes ! Hamm..I don't know. How can I check this ? it's my very first day with Webpack.

Comment: Oh sorry about assuming that you would know that. whats the script you run to start your dev environment?

Comment: this one: webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080

Comment: Ok, then try running this one `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --hot --port 8080`